# ERROR_ZERO_CAPTCHA_FILESIZE - Как исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Есть код:

```
def get_download_link_sharewood(self, link, log, password):
    resp1 = self.session.get('https://s1.sharewood.co/login/login', headers=self.session.headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp1.content, 'lxml')
    block = soup.find_all('dl', class_='formRow')[2].find_all('div')[1]
    sitekey = block['data-sitekey']

    captcha_params = {
        'key': rucaptcha_token,
        'method': 'hcaptcha',
        'sitekey': sitekey,
        'pageurl': 'https://s1.sharewood.co/login/login',
    }

    captcha_resp = self.session.post('http://rucaptcha.com/in.php', params=captcha_params)
    id_ = captcha_resp.text.split('|')[1]

    solve_captcha_params = {
        'key': rucaptcha_token,
        'action': 'get',
        'id': id_,
        'invisible': 1
    }
    time.sleep(15)
    captcha_solve = self.session.get('http://rucaptcha.com/in.php', params=solve_captcha_params)
    print(captcha_solve.text)

    params = {
        'login': log,
        'password': password
    }
```

И все время пишет ERROR_ZERO_CAPTCHA_FILESIZE. В оф. документации RuCaptcha пишет, что ошибка связана с тем, что передаваемый размер изображения меньше 100 байт. Как такое может быть и как это исправить? POST-запрос на решение капчи обрабатывается корректно и присылает ID.